# Writing expectation like Shiryaev

Tags: typography

I want to know how to get this symbol for Expectation. I tried with Mathpix to know the command, but it doesn't help.

Thanks! 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your formula using the default fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mathsf{E}\left[g(\theta) \mid \xi = x_j\right]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need the \left` and `\right` sizing directives?